# How can I give focus to WinJS.UI.settingsFlyout after animation?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I'm invoking a WinJS.UI.settingsFlyout element via Javascript using WinJS.  Inside the HTML element of the settingsFlyout, I have a text input field that I would like to receive focus after the animation of the flyout occurs.  I've tried to use jQuery's .focus() method, but it does not work because I do not think the flyout is focused after it completes its animation.  I have to click twice on the input field to begin typing.  I click once to get the flyout in focus, and then click another time to get the field in focus.  Quite annoying.  Is there a way to implement auto focusing of input fields within a WinJS.UI.settingsFlyout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
settingsFlyout.addEventListener("aftershow", function(){
   $('#inputId').focus();
});
```